# Flutter - How to avoid repeating StreamBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart

in my app I often need a list of objects that I get with 3 StreamBuilders. I want to avoid repeating those StreamBuilders every time.

So I tried to do a Stateful Widget that contains my 3 StreamBuilders with a Widget child argument returned by the last StreamBuilder.
But it doesn't work. The datas are not communicated to the child Widget.
What is the good way to do it please?

Comment: Can you add the codes of this issue? It will be helpful to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on **StreamBuilder()**
2. Then **right click** => select **Refactor** form the options => Click on **Extract Flutter Widget**
3. Now create a file with any name like streambuilder_helper.dart
4. Cut and paste the Extracted Widget in this file. Make sure to import **material.dart**
5. Now suppose you want to use this anywhere in your app just import the file **streambuilder_helper.dart**
6. While creating this flutter widget if you want to use this anywhere make sure to create several finals like

   final myStream;

and then suppose the name of the flutter widget you defined is **myStreamBuilder()** then you have to create
`myStreamBuilder({});` inside the flutter widget
and define this myStream final in it

```
myStreamBuilder({this.myStream});
```

and finally replace the hard coded code with your final in the StreamBuilder.